# Upgrading Raid Card - import configuration - Perc 5

Tags: raid, dell, dell-perc, lsi

I am upgrading my Perc 5 to a Perc 5i (allegedly lets me have hot spares and power management).  When I put the 5i card in and connect the drives, it does not recognise the previous RAID configuration. Import foreign disks is grayed out.  How do I get this new card installed without having to rebuild this server.  If I rebuild the array do I lose all data?

Comment: You might check with the manufacturer for guidance/support on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like these two cards are as related as they seem; they don't play nice together.  Creating a disk image with Acronis and then restoring was the only option that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Dell has instructions to do this. They're located here:

http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/software/svradmin/5.0/en/omss_ug/html/movdisks.html